# In EF core 7.0.7: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object - only for Applying migration for RenameColumn

Tags: c#, mysql, migration, nullreferenceexception, ef-core-7.0

Using EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.7 in an ASP.NET Core project, database with Mysql
When Applying migration to rename column with update-database command, I get error **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.
Others types of migration are run without problems in the same entity

I created another entity Test and tried to rename a column with migration and gave the same problem

Comment: Better to share more details, especially callstack (not images). Otherwise your question will be ignored.